# Can Sump pump basin depth cause damage

Tags: foundation, sump-pump

I have a dirt basement and replaced a bug-box sump in 5 gallon bucket setup, with a 1/3 HP submersible iron pump.  The new basin is about three feet deep - I drilled some holes in it, and added garden fabric around the outside and drainage stone around the unit.

My house is located on a river and the street has water problems in the basements.  Yesterday I monitored the system and the pump would kick on every 60-90 minutes...  I don't care about the pump running, I bought it to.

I question whether the depth of the basin is drawing too much water out of the ground.  Can that be problematic to my home e.g. the foundation?

Comment: Most sump pump pits made for homes are around at least three feet deep.  Do doubt a sump pump can remove enough water to be a concern, even running 24/7.

Comment: Water under and around the foundation should be cause for concern, not lack of water.

Comment: Most sumps I have seen were in basement floors ; so nominally 10 feet below the floor of the house. I doubt your few feet will cause any problem.

Comment: Make sure you are pumping it far enough away that it is not percolating down the foundation and being pumped out again.

Answer (score 1):

You done good.

It's doing its job and no risk of damage; sounds like you set it up perfect. The reason for more frequent kicks is for every increment you go deeper, you add that much more water spilling into the bucket but a sump float has a fixed height it kicks on. Your flow rate went up; the good news us you're draining more water from your basement than before which can add a nice bit of buffer relieving water further back from your sump pit than before.